# I keep getting an "Scanner cannot be resolved to a type" error. I am using Java and Visual Studio and this is for a beginner Java class

Tags: java, visual-studio, java.util.scanner

This is for a beginner java class.  I keep getting an "Scanner cannot be resolved to a type" error. I am using Visual Studio and JDK 16.0.2 I also just installed Visual Studio and installed Java on this laptop. I am writing this Mortgage Calculator program for my class and it worked before I added the while loops for catching user input error.  Now it gives me the "scanner" error when it didn't before.  I added and moved around a few code lines and all the sudden it gives me this "scanner" error. Below is the whole code:

```
  package com.phillip;
  import java.text.NumberFormat;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Main{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
              final byte MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;
              final byte PERCENT = 100;

              int principal = 0;
              float monthlyInterest = 0;
              int numberOfPayments = 0;

              Scanner scanner = new Scannner(System.in);

              while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Principal: ");
                    principal = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (principal >= 1000 && principal <= 1_000_000) {
                          break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Enter a value between 1000 and 1000000");
              }

              while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Annual Interest Rate: ");
                    float annualInterest = scanner.nextFloat();
                    if (annualInterest >= 1 && annualInterest <= 30) {
                          monthlyInterest = annualInterest / PERCENT / MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
                          break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Enter a value between 1 and 30");
              }

              while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Period (Years): ");
                    byte years = scanner.nextByte();
                    if (years >= 1 && years <= 30) {
                          numberOfPayments = years * MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
                          break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Enter a value between 1 & 30");
              }

              double mortgage = principal 
                    * (monthlyInterest * Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments)) 
                    / (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - 1);

              String mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mortgage);
              System.out.println("Mortgage: " + mortgageFormatted);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Check this line: `Scanner scanner = new Scannner(System.in);`.  -> Sca**nnn**er

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a typo

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scannner(System.in);
```

'Scannner' instead of 'Scanner'

Comment: Ok after I fixed the typo "scanner" now I run it first time works perfectly fine and then second time it gives me a "Resource leak: scanner is never closed" error under the squiqqly line in code editor and under the output terminal it gives me this error :    (Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException)

Comment: After you have finished using the Scanner object, you should call 'scanner.close()'

Comment: Otherwise, the scanner object takes up memory, and as the error message says, it 'leaks'. I.e. the program continues to allocate memory every time you create a new scanner object, put doesn't deallocate it.

Comment: The scanner.close() helped fixed my problems.  Well this is kind of weird because in my online tutorial it didn't tell me to close the scanner.  Am I missing something? it worked before the loops was added.  Is it safe to assume that all Scanner objects must be closed in all programs?

Comment: Yes, I cannot think of a case where you would not close the scanner object. Java does have a garbage collector which cleans up any not-in-use allocated memory at the end of a program's life, but it's generally best to manually close the object